# How to raise a psycopg2 ProgrammingError with pgerror set?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a try except block where I execute a statement but there is a chance that it may raise a psycopg2 ProgrammingError. I have it set up to handle the error just fine but I am finding it difficult to mock. I need to be able to set the pgerror property of the ProgrammingError but it is a read only property.

```
>>> e = ProgrammingError()
>>> e.pgerror = 'an error'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

I have also tried to set the pgerror value when I create the error

```
>>> e = ProgrammingError(pgerror='an error')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ProgrammingError() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is there another way I could set the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I could use the dunder setstate to set the value of pgerror

```
e = ProgrammingError()
e.__setstate__({"pgerror": "an eror"})
raise e
```

Then when the error is caught it will have the pgerror property set to `an error`

Comment: I have a similar issue. However, I want to set the value of e.diag.message_detail. With the above __setstate__() method I am able to set the value of pgerror, how can I achieve the same for e.diag.message_detail?